# How to average lists on different columns using polars LazyFrame

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars `LazyFrame` which has 3 columns of type nullable `list[f64]`, something like this.

```py
import polars as pl

lf = pl.DataFrame({
    "1": [
        [0.0, 1.1, 2.2],
        [0.0, 1.1, 2.2],
        [0.0, 1.1, 2.2],
        None,
    ],
    "2": [
        [0.3, 1.3, 2.3],
        [0.4, 1.4, 2.4],
        [0.5, 1.5, 2.5],
        None,
    ],
    "3": [
        [0.7, 1.7, 2.7],
        None,
        [0.9, 1.9, 2.9],
        None,
    ],
}).lazy()
```

```
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ 1               ┆ 2               ┆ 3               │
│ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---             │
│ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.3, 1.3, 2.3] ┆ [0.7, 1.7, 2.7] │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.4, 1.4, 2.4] ┆ null            │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.5, 1.5, 2.5] ┆ [0.9, 1.9, 2.9] │
│ null            ┆ null            ┆ null            │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

I need to add a column with the average of the three column's lists, furthermore

- when in a row there are only `null`, then avg will be a zeros-filled list of fixed length `3`
- when one item is `null` the average will be computed on the non-null lists

For "average of the lists" I mean the element-wise sum divided by the number of lists involved in the sum.

So in the first row I want:

```
[
    0.0 + 0.3 + 0.7,
    1.1 + 1.3 + 1.7,
    2.2 + 2.3 + 2.7
] / 3
=
[
    1.0, 4.1, 7.2
] / 3
=
[0.33, 1.36, 2.40]
```

In the second row: `[0.0 + 0.4, 1.1 + 1.4, 2.2 + 2.4] / 2 = [0.4, 2.8, 4.6] / 2 = [0.2, 1.4, 2.3]`.

In the last row: `[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]`.

I found a way to sum the columns

```py
lf.select(
    pl.sum_horizontal(
        pl.col("*").list.explode()
    ).reshape((1, -1)).alias("sum"),
).collect()
```

But this only works when all the items in row are non-null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could expand on your initial attempt by replacing `null` with `[0, 0, 0]` and manually creating a list of `[width, width, width]` to divide by.

```
width = pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null()) 

df.with_columns(avg = 
   (pl.sum_horizontal(
      pl.when(pl.all().is_null()).then([0, 0, 0]).otherwise(pl.all()).list.explode()
   ) / pl.concat_list(width, width, width).list.explode())
   .fill_nan(0)
   .reshape((-1, 3))
)
```

```
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ 1               ┆ 2               ┆ 3               ┆ avg                       │
│ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---                       │
│ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]                 │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.3, 1.3, 2.3] ┆ [0.7, 1.7, 2.7] ┆ [0.333333, 1.366667, 2.4] │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.4, 1.4, 2.4] ┆ null            ┆ [0.2, 1.25, 2.3]          │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.5, 1.5, 2.5] ┆ [0.9, 1.9, 2.9] ┆ [0.466667, 1.5, 2.533333] │
│ null            ┆ null            ┆ null            ┆ [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]           │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

Or as a possible function:

```
def list_avg(size):
    # replace `null` with lists of `0`
    cols = pl.when(pl.all().is_null()).then([0] * size).otherwise(pl.all())
    cols = cols.list.explode()
    
    # number of non-null columns
    num_cols = pl.sum_horizontal(pl.all().is_not_null()) 
    num_cols = pl.concat_list([num_cols] * size).list.explode()
    
    return (pl.sum_horizontal(cols) / num_cols).fill_nan(0).reshape((-1, size))
    
    
df.with_columns(avg = list_avg(size=3))
```

Comment: To create the list of [width, width, width] I used *[width for _ in range(3)], this way I can replace that 3 with the length of the list

Comment: Yeah, good point. As it is somewhat complex - maybe creating a function could be useful. I've updated with an example.

Answer (score 2):

```py
lf.with_columns(
    avg=pl.when(pl.all_horizontal(pl.all().is_null()))
    .then([0, 0, 0])
    .otherwise(
        pl.reduce(
            lambda acc, x: pl.when(x.is_null())
            .then(acc)
            .when(acc.is_null())
            .then(x)
            .otherwise(acc.list.concat(x)),
            pl.all(),
        )
    )
).with_columns(
    avg=pl.concat_list(
        pl.col('avg')
        .list.take(pl.int_ranges(i, pl.col('avg').list.lengths(), 3))
        .list.sum()
        / (pl.col('avg').list.lengths() / 3)
        for i in range(3)
    )
).collect()
```

```py
shape: (4, 4)
┌─────────────────┬─────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────────────────┐
│ 1               ┆ 2               ┆ 3               ┆ avg                       │
│ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---             ┆ ---                       │
│ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]       ┆ list[f64]                 │
╞═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════════╡
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.3, 1.3, 2.3] ┆ [0.7, 1.7, 2.7] ┆ [0.333333, 1.366667, 2.4] │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.4, 1.4, 2.4] ┆ null            ┆ [0.2, 1.25, 2.3]          │
│ [0.0, 1.1, 2.2] ┆ [0.5, 1.5, 2.5] ┆ [0.9, 1.9, 2.9] ┆ [0.466667, 1.5, 2.533333] │
│ null            ┆ null            ┆ null            ┆ [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]           │
└─────────────────┴─────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────────────────┘
```

The main step here is a [`pl.reduce`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.reduce.html#polars.reduce) (horizontal, row-wise fold reduction) where if the intermediate element `x` is null, we do nothing (return `acc` in that intermediate step), or vice versa, or otherwise concatenate the lists all together. So all the numbers are there to do the calculation, then it comes down to appropriately `take`-ing each set of elements to do math on.

Some of these `3`s should be generalizable as `len(lf.columns)` before the entire operation.